# Windows 10 reboots with missing event logs

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, reboot

So for quite some time now, my computer is hard rebooting itself. It looks something like I would unplug power to it and then turns itself on again. I thought It could be overheating, however I opened and cleared everything and the problem keeps occurring. I was thinking that this could be problem with Windows so I checked Event Viewer for logs, and every time the shutdown occurs there is no logs for 30 minutes, when the computer turns itself back on it says that the computer was shut down 30 minutes ago, unsafely.

Also every time the computer restarts this way I got this message `Default Radeon WattMan settings have been restored due to unexpected system failure`
Which makes me think it has something to do with graphics card.

Is there a way to fix this problem **without reinstalling / deleting graphics drivers**. This is because every time I tried to reinstall or update graphics drivers, the drivers stop functioning, and I have to do factory reset on computer. (Deleting updated driver and then installing it back from AMD site does not help at all, and installation always finishes with warnings.

I am unhappy user of this graphics card: AMD R5 330
My computer also features A10-7800 Radeon R7 Processor

Edit: Once again I tried updating my graphics drivers from version 16.6 to 17.2.1. After installation I still got version 16.6, and updating resulted with warning

```
<package>
    <description>AMD Display Driver</description>
    <result>Fail</result>
    <version>15.200.1055.0000</version>
    <size>90 </size>
</package>
```

Comment: What kind of power supply do you have?

Comment: according to specification from HP it should have 180 W uATX Energy Star 6.0 internal power supply

Comment: That is nowhere near powerful enough.That is definitely the problem.

Comment: great pre built computer that is not even compatible with itself, that started to becoming trash just after warranty expired.

Comment: If you must buy a pre-built computer, buy from Dell.  Everyone else is just terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
2. From the menu that appears, choose "System". The System applet appears.
3. From the left-hand pane, choose "Advanced system settings". The System Properties dialog box appears on "Advanced" tab.
4. From the "Startup and Recovery" section near the bottom, choose "Settings..." button. The Startup and Recovery dialog box appears.
5. Uncheck "automatically restart" and press the OK button.
6. Press OK again and close the System applet.

This will cause your system to show you a critical error message instead of restarting itself. Now, from now on, if the system continued to restart itself, you will know that it is a hardware problem. On the other hand, if you see a critical error message instead, you will have a clue for troubleshooting.

> Also every time the computer restarts this way I got this message `Default Radeon WattMan settings have been restored due to unexpected system failure` Which makes me think it has something to do with graphics card.

I find your opinion strange. Your system unexpectedly shut down and you lost your video driver settings. The former could be the cause of the latter.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the graphics card sometimes causes BSODS, with thread_stuck_in_device_driver, this is why I said that I was thinking it is caused by Video Driver

Comment: If it were a BSOD then it would be in the system log.

Comment: well sometimes there is BSOD other times the computer just shuts hard reboots